# Sitecore 6.6 and Lucene upgrade issue

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

We recently upgraded to Sitecore 6.6 and are running into issues with the search and crawl functionality from Lucene since 6.6 uses a newer version and has some of the methods/functions have been made obsolete.

The code below used to work fine with the previous version of Lucene.NET 2.3 but isn't working in 2.9. Can you tell us what we are doing wrong and help us rectify this piece of code? The error we get while compiling is

```
`Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher` does not contain a definition for 'Search'
and no extension method 'Search' accepting a first argument of type 
`Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher` could be found (are you missing a using 
directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This error happens on this line - `Sitecore.Search.SearchHits hits = new SearchHits(context.Searcher.Search(query,sort));`. I'm guessing that it will be a simple fix but I'm unsure of how to go  about fixing it.

```cs
private static SearchResultCollection GetSearchResults(Query query, Sort sort, int startingIndex, int getCount, out int totalHits)
{
    SearchResultCollection retVal = new SearchResultCollection();
    Sitecore.Search.Index searchIndex = Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.GetIndex("content");
    using (Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
    {
        Sitecore.Search.SearchHits hits = new SearchHits(context.Searcher.Search(query,sort));
        totalHits = hits.Length;
        //since index is zero based... adjust the numbers 
        startingIndex = (startingIndex - 1) * getCount;
        getCount = (getCount > totalHits || totalHits < startingIndex + getCount) 
            ? hits.Length - startingIndex : getCount;
        retVal = hits.FetchResults(startingIndex, getCount);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sitecore 6.6** uses **Lucene 2.9**. The code below is your code updated to support the newer version of **Lucene**. There are 2 major changes:

1. `Search` method is executed with 2 additional parameters (`Filter` which is set to `null` and `maxDocs` which is set to `int.MaxValue`).
2. `SearchHits` constructor takes `IndexReader` instance as the second parameter.

Code below should work exactly as you expect.

```cs
using (Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext context = searchIndex.CreateSearchContext())
{
    TopFieldDocs docs = context.Searcher.Search(query, null, int.MaxValue, sort);
    Sitecore.Search.SearchHits hits = new SearchHits(docs, context.Searcher.GetIndexReader());
    totalHits = hits.Length;
    startingIndex = (startingIndex - 1) * getCount;
    getCount = (getCount > totalHits || totalHits < startingIndex + getCount) ? hits.Length - startingIndex : getCount;
    retVal = hits.FetchResults(startingIndex, getCount);
}
```

Comment: Made the change. Fire in the hole! :)

Comment: With your code, I'm getting the following error - Invalid shift value in prefixCoded string (is encoded value really an INT?)

Comment: Any stacktrace? Just found on google a guy having same problem as you and his answer was "I index a double for the Numeric field but my Sortfield was setup as a float."

Comment: I was able to get it working using your code. The error I received was on a field that was not properly indexed. Once I fixed that issue, it all started working. Thanks for the input again.

Answer (score 3):

Not terribly familiar with Sitecore, but `Searcher.search(Query, Sort)` was deprecated in Lucene 2.9, and looks like wasn't present at all in Lucene.Net.  Instead, call [`Searcher.search(Query, Filter, int, Sort)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort)). The second argument (Filter) can be null, and the third (int) indicates the number of documents to return from the search.